# Mule 4 - How to remove special characters in output

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

Input:

[
{
"payload": "{\n "qty": 6.00,\n      "itemKey": "55555"\n    }\n  ],\n  "deliveryNote": "",\n  "deliveryDate": "2022-10-22T00:00:00.000Z",\n  "shoppingCartId": "2",\n  "poNumber": "iisdown",\n  "customerKey": "44444",\n  "id": "9018A0000007OGrQAM"\n}"
}
]

How should i write my dataweave expression to have the following output:

{
"id": "9018A0000007OGrQAM",
"customerKey": "44444",
"deliveryDate": "2022-10-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"poNumber": "testingpo",
"shoppingCartId": "2",
"deliveryNote": "testing",
"lines": [
{
"itemKey": "55555",
"qty": 5
}
]
}

Comment: can you share some details like What sort of input type are you receiving, is it from a connector? . it's not a valid json in first place to work with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are no special characters in the payload. The input has a JSON as a string value. JSON processors need to escape the characters inside that string that are used by JSON to avoid generating invalid JSON. So quotes are escaped with a backslash `\` character and new lines are represented by a `\n`, as usual in many languages. If you want to parse that value and recover the JSON value you can use the read() function of DataWeave.

Note that it will fail for your input because it contains and invalid JSON, even if escaped. If the input can not be fixed you can not use read() and will need to use some string functions like replace() to parse it manually.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload[0].payload, "application/json")
```

I have no idea how you expect to obtain the structure of the output since you didn't clarify it and the question is about 'special characters' only. However it doesn't seem that the input contains all the data to obtain that expected output.